# Trust Access database automatically

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I created a tool which imports .txt (via Access macro) then runs some reports on it.

Now the idea is that the users copy an excel tool together with a empty template database, and then import their own data into it.  The **the problem I am running into, is that the new database is not trusted, so the macros are disabled**.

Answer (score 1):

Add some folder into "Trusted location" and put your database into this folder.

MS Access 2010

[image]

Comment: Actually my users don't actually have MSAccess... So I can't have them open up Access Options to add a trusted location.  I just have to test if my code works without a Access License.  Will update the comment if it works.

Comment: the same option available in Excel.

Comment: Bleah, it doesn't work without an access license.  So all the code will have to be ADODB code, which is just so much more effort to execute, but not impossible in this instance, but in many instances you would like to run VBA code which aren't available via ADO.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I found to this problem is to move your database code to the excel spreadsheet, which leaves your DB without the need to be trusted.

Seemingly you can do everything you want to do via the DB's vba module from the access object in Excel.

Access Code:

```
Application.DoCmd.OpenQuery "DelData"
Application.DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, "DataImport", "StoreGroupingDrop", ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\StoreGrouping.txt", True
Applicaiton.DoCmd.OpenQuery "DelExtraWeekData"
```

Excel Code:

```
Dim db As Object
Set db = CreateObject("Access.Application")

db.OpenCurrentDatabase (ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\StoreGrouping.accdb")
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
'db.Run "DoImports"

' Implement "DoImports" from excel, because the Access VBA is not inherently trusted
db.DoCmd.OpenQuery "DelData"
db.DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, "DataImport", "StoreGroupingDrop", ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\StoreGrouping.txt", True
db.DoCmd.OpenQuery "DelExtraWeekData"
db.Application.Quit
```